# Change PHP array format from one to another

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to transform an PHP array from one format to another.

My array looks like:

```
array (size=5)
  0 =>
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'userName' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'thename' (length=7)
  1 =>
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'email' (length=5)
      'value' => string 'email@email.com' (length=15)
  2 =>
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'password' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'thepassword' (length=11)
  3 =>
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'confirmPassword' (length=15)
      'value' => string 'thepassword' (length=11)
  4 =>
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'postcode' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'postcode' (length=8)
```

And I need to re-format it to this:

```
array("userName" => "thename",
      "email" => "email@email.com",
      "password" => "thepassword",
      "confirmPassword" => "thepassword",
      "postcode" => "postcode"
     );
```

I just can't figure it out.. Please help :)

Comment: haters gonna hate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 5.5, PHP has a wonderful built-in function called [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) that lets you do

```
$newArray = array_column($array, 'value', 'name');
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem comes up every day. Why stress out over finding a specialized function to do the job when it is very straightforward to loop through the original array and make a new one?

```
// Assume $old_array is the one you have that you are working with
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $a)
    $new_array[$a['name']] = $a['value'];
```

That's it. The $new_array has name from the original array in the indexes and value from the original array in the values.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet:

```
$result = array();
foreach($orig as $def) {
    $result[$def['name']] = $def['value'];
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
$orig = array (
    array (
      'name' => 'userName',
      'value' => 'thename',
    ),
    array (
      'name' => 'email',
      'value' => 'email@email.com',
    ),
    array (
      'name' => 'password',
      'value' => 'thepassword',
    ),
    array (
      'name' => 'confirmPassword',
      'value' => 'thepassword',
    ),
    array (
      'name' => 'postcode',
      'value' => 'postcode',
    ),
);

$result = array();
foreach($orig as $def) {
    $result[$def['name']] = $def['value'];
}

echo '<pre>'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<h3>Original Array</h3>'.PHP_EOL;
var_dump($orig);
echo '<h3>Resulting Array</h3>'.PHP_EOL;
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>'.PHP_EOL;
```